# COM does not work in IIS PHP version 7.2.9

Tags: php, .net, iis, com, php-extension

I'm having an issue trying to get COM to work on my local Internet Information Services (IIS) server running php:
"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'COM' not found in ..."

HTML,PHP,CSS only (PHP version 7.2.9)
new COM("ADODB.Connection")

I have reviewed the following link:
[PHP - COM does not work in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16132340/php-com-does-not-work-in-iis)
and added:

```
[COM_DOT_NET] 
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
```

to both php.ini files (i.e., development and production), but the error remains.

I suspect this has something to do with the 7.2.9 version of PHP I have installed with IIS. What is the proper .dll reference for the php.ini files?

Comment: the proper dll is the one in your php's extensions directory..  did you restart the web server after making changes?  Did you verify the correct ini file with phpinfo?

Comment: "php_com_dotnet.dll " is the .dll in my extensions directory. Is the php.ini syntax reference above correct for PHP version 7.2.9? Yes, the web server was restarted. No I did not check phpinfo, looking at it now it is attempting to reference C:/windows yet no php.ini file is found there?

Comment: Well, sounds like you have php misconfigured then

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll head down that route to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is highly unlikely that PHP is configured to load `php.ini-development` nor `php.ini-production` as these files exist mainly for convenience. You need to copy one of those into a `php.ini` file.

After you've made the necessary changes, you will likely need to restart your web server.

Additionally, use `phpinfo();` to see your PHP's configuration and look for a row named:

> Loaded Configuration File

This will tell you which ini file is loaded into PHP's memory.

`phpinfo()` will also let you know which extensions have been enabled.

If you still cannot get the COM extension loaded then you need to check your PHP error logs because they could indicate that you have an incorrect DLL file.